# Output parameter or return struct in C11?

Tags: c, c11

I know C++11 has move semantics, which mean you can directly return a struct from a function and not worry about it being copied (assuming a simple struct), as opposed to writing the struct through an output parameter.

Does C11 have anything like this? Or do returned structs still get copied every time? Are output parameters still the "best practice" here?

Comment: For biggish structures, use output (pointer) parameters.  For small structures, there's no particular need to worry.  You need to judge where the breakpoint between small and big occurs; I'd probably start thinking about the issue at 16 bytes or so.

Comment: Definitely. My question was whether this was still a concern at all. From your answer, it sounds like return structs are indeed still being copied every time.

Comment: I've not bothered to look to see what happens; (small) return values work, and the performance isn't bad enough to make me worry.  If you don't have a reason to look at the performance, you don't need to worry.  If you do have a reason to worry, then you need to understand the specific compilers you're targeting.  The standard doesn't say how the effect is to be achieved; it just says it must be achieved.  Different compilers on different platforms may do it differently; welcome to the real world.  So, before doing any hard work on the subject, check to ensure it is a measurable problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is some confusion here which should be clarified.  The *semantics* and the *implementation* of C++ are different.

- "Move" versus "copy" in C++ is just a question of which constructor (or `operator=`) you are invoking.
- The question of whether the representation of the structure's members is copied is an entirely separate question.  In other words, "does the processor have to move these bytes around?" is not part of the language semantics.

### Semantics

```
MyClass func() {
    MyClass x;
    x.method(...);
    ...
    return x;
}
```

This returns using move semantics if available, but even prior to C++11, return value optimization was available.

The reason why we prefer to use move semantics is because moving an object doesn't cause a deep copy, e.g., if you move a `std::vector<T>` you don't have to copy all of the `T`.  However, you are still copying data!  So, `std::move(x)` is *semantically speaking* a move operation (think of it as using linear rather than classical logic) but it is still implemented by copying data in memory.

Unless your ABI lets you avoid the copy.  Which brings us to...

### Implementation

When you call a function that returns a large structure (the term "large" is relative, it might only be a few words), most ABIs will call for that structure to be passed by reference to the function.  So when you write something like this:

```
MyClass func() { ... }
```

Once you look at it in assembly, it might look something more like this:

```
void func(MyClass *ptr) { ... }
```

Of course, this is a simplification!  The pointer is usually implicit.  But the important point is that we are already avoiding a copy, *sometimes*.

### Case study

Here is a simple example:

```
struct big {
    int x[100];
};

struct big func1(void);

int func2() {
    struct big x = func1();
    struct big y = func1();
    return x.x[0] + y.x[0];
}
```

When I compile this with `gcc -O2` on x64, I get the following assembly output:

```
    subq    $808, %rsp
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    call    func1
    leaq    400(%rsp), %rdi
    call    func1
    movl    400(%rsp), %eax
    addl    (%rsp), %eax
    addq    $808, %rsp
    ret
```

You can see that *nowhere* is `struct big` copied.  The result from `func2()` simply gets placed on the stack for `func1()`, and then the stack gets moved so the next result gets placed elsewhere.

### However

- In common ABIs, large function results won't get threaded through multiple function stacks.  Returning `x` or `y` from `func2()` above will result in the structure being copied.
- But remember!  This has nothing to do with *move semantics* versus *copy semantics*, because the structure data getting copied is just an implementation detail rather than language semantics.  In C++, using `std::move()` may still result in the structure getting copied, it just won't invoke the copy constructor.

The conclusion: returning a large structure from either C or C++ may result in copying the structure, *depending* on the particulars of the ABI, how the function is optimized, and the code in question.  However, I wouldn't worry about it if the structure is only a few words long.

Comment: Wow. Awesome clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nairou, in the last paragraph do you mean, that for some ABIs we can't assume RVO (return value optimisation) of a temporary variable, not bound to any references will be applied? I mean for case lik ethe below one:
`struct Value
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

Value CreateValue(int x, int y, int z)
{
    Value v;
    v.a = CalculateA(x);
    v.b = CalculateB(y, z);
    return v;
}`

Comment: @ElaMakiej: In that example, RVO is irrelevant.  Remember that RVO means the compiler can omit a call to `operator=` in certain circumstances.  However, you didn't define `operator=` so there is nothing for the compiler to optimize out, at least not with RVO.

Comment: Or to put it more precisely, the type is trivially copyable so the compiler has a lot of freedom.

Comment: "In common ABIs, large function results won't get threaded through multiple function stacks. Returning x or y from func2() above will result in the structure being copied." 

I was not able to reproduce this. I was unable to get the compiler to copy the structure even after passing the returned struct through multiple functions. See https://godbolt.org/z/6c5q188qx